# Nuget Gallery package source not found

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-server, nugetgallery

I have set up NugetGallery https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery on my own server and am able to access the UI and perform all operations. However, I have been unable to locate the link that needs to be added to the Visual Studio NuGet package source. Despite extensive searching, I have not been able to find any documentation about it. Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?

I've used https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery#deploy-locally this **Deploy locally** portion to deploy NugetGallery

I've tried with https://localhost/v3/index.json, which gives an error. `Unable to load the service index for https://localhost/v3/index.json. Response status code does not indicate successL 404 (Not Found).`

Also, I've tried with https://localhost/api/v2/, which does not give an error but does not find any package that I've uploaded.